# hacer un print con salto de linea en los resultados

Tags: python, print, salto-de-linea

soy nuevo y me gustaría poder hacer un print con strings y variables y que estos quedaran en una lista, lo he intentado con \n pero a partir del segundo salto que quiero hacer no me reconoce las variables, he intentado con end= '\n' y tampoco solo he conseguido que lo imprima todo en una misma fila,tambien he tratado con ''' pero nada, no se si en pythom esto que quiero hacer no se puede o es por desconocimiento, tampoco pasa nada si hago 3 prints, pero deseo saber si es posible de alguna forma

## Así si me reconoce las variables pero no funcionaba

```
print(f"La edad multiplicada por 2 es:", edad2, end='\n'
"Si esto lo elevamos a 3 es:", edad3, end='\n'
"Si al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es:", edad4)
```

## Así las deja de reconocer en la potencia

```
print("La edad multiplicada por 2 es:", edad2 , \n 
      "Si esto lo elevamos a 3 es:", edad3,\n 
      "Si al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es:",   edad4)
```

## Esta es la única forma de que lo imprima todo pero no es en lista

```
print("La edad multiplicada por 2 es:", edad2 , "Si esto lo elevamos a 3 es:", edad3, "Si al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es:",   edad4)
```

Comment: Tienes que usar varios prints, uno por línea.

Comment: Al menos deberías leer la documentación de `print()` (y de funciones en general): 1) `print()` agrega un `\n` por default. 2) `end=` es un parámetro con nombre, y sólo lo puedes poner una vez en la llamada. 3) `end=` no inserta nada "entremedio" de los strings; sólo dice el carácter a usar al final de la línea.

Answer (score 0):

para diferentes líneas lo que necesitas es "\n" o 'n' para que se formatee correctamente ejemplo:

```
edad2=1; #numero random para pruebas
edad3=1;
edad4=1;
print("La edad multiplicada por 2 es:", edad2, '\n'
"Si esto lo elevamos a 3 es:", edad3, "\n"
"Si al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es:", edad4)#"\n" '\n' es el carácter salto de línea
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp #simulador con ejemplos más lectura recomendada (inglés)

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo tu código solo te falta añadir `\n` entre cada frase.

```
edad1, edad2, edad3, edad4 = 2, 4, 6, 20
print("La edad multiplicada por 2 es:", edad2 , "\nSi esto lo elevamos a 3 es:", edad3, "\nSi al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es:", edad4)
```

Pero **tienes muchas variables que no te hacen falta**, puedes hacer todos los cálculos en el `print`:

```
edad = 23
print(f"La edad multiplicada por 2 es: {edad*2}\nSi esto lo elevamos a 3 es: {edad**3}\nSi al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es: {edad**3-100}")
```

Para el caso que tú planteas, **varios textos con sus resultados** puede interesarte guardar los textos en una lista y los resultados en otra, después unes los datos de cada lista.

```
textos = ["La edad multiplicada por 2 es:", "Si esto lo elevamos a 3 es:", "Si al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es:"]
valores = [ 4, 6, 20]

for i in range(len(textos)):
    print(f'{textos[i]} {valores[i]}')
```

También se puede resolver con `zip`

```
textos = ["La edad multiplicada por 2 es:", "Si esto lo elevamos a 3 es:", "Si al resultado de esto le restamos 100 es:"]
valores = [ 4, 6, 20]

for texto, valor in zip(textos, valores):
    print(f'{texto} {valor}')
```